# Gitlab 'include local' from same project but different directory

Tags: gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci

So lets say I have a project structure like:

```
project-fancy-name
    -> jobs
        -> build
            - build-maven.yml
        -> defaults
            - maven-defaults.yml
```

And in the `build-maven.yml` I want to include the `defaults-maven.yml` file.

I have tried the below combinations but all seem to give me this error or similar:`Local file defaults/maven-defaults.yml does not exist!`

```
include:
  - local: defaults/maven-defaults.yml


include:
  - local: /defaults/maven-defaults.yml


include:
  - local: ./defaults/maven-defaults.yml


include:
  - local: ../defaults/maven-defaults.yml
```

I was under the impression that using `../` may have gone back a directory but doesn't seem to be the case.

So what would the correct syntax be for including the local file `maven-defaults.yml` in the `build-maven.yml` file?

I have read the [Gitlab Include](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html) reference material but it doesn't seem to give any examples that would work here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`include:` paths are relative to the project root, not relative to the file location. So just include the full path, relative to the project root:

```yaml
include:
  - local: jobs/defaults/maven-defaults.yml
```